# Undefined function when using IFFE (Immediately-invoked function expression)

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined-function

I've got a function which I've assigned to a variable and when I instantly invoice it with IFFE, I get an undefined error.

```
<script>
    "use strict";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var enableBulkAction = function () {
            if ($("#frmProductManagement input:checkbox:checked").length > 0) {
                // any one is checked
                $('#ddlBulkAction').prop("enabled", "enabled");
            } else {
                // none is checked
                $('#ddlBulkAction').prop("disabled", "disabled");
            }
        }();


        $('#chkTableAll').click(function () {
            var checkedStatus = this.checked;
            $('#tblProductsManagements tbody tr').find('td:first :checkbox').each(function () {
                $(this).prop('checked', checkedStatus);
                enableBulkAction();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

enableBulkAction(); is not a function even though it should be in scope. Anyone know what I've forgotten to do?

Comment: I'm not sure why I got down voted. It's just a simple inline script I'm using in ASP.NET MVC for the purpose of a prototype.

Comment: Voting to close as typo: You have `()` after the closing `}` of the function expression, which means you're **calling** your function and assigning the *result* of calling it to `enableBulkAction`. Since it doesn't return anything, that result is `undefined`. Just remove the `()`, so that you're assigning the function (not its result) to `enableBulkAction`. *(not my dv)*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That's called an IFFE so it fires the function once it's parsed but for the sake of getting it working I've gotten rid of it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you are not supposed to use IIFE along with some piece of jQuery code.

Comment: Actually, it's called an IIFE (inline-invoked function expression). I know what it is. The problem is that you don't want one here. You want to create a function and store a reference to it in `enableBulkAction`. You don't want to create *and call it* and store its result in `enableBulkAction`.

Comment: @SagarV: Well, there are times you would, this just isn't one of them.

Comment: Voted to close, but agree with OP though, that this does not deserve down votes.

Comment: @rasmeister: Yeah. Anyone can make a mistake, and the code is there, and the question is clear. (Nick - Since it is effectively a typo, I suggest just deleting it.The full close reason text is: *"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting."* which seems to apply here. Happy coding!)

Comment: Base on OP's response I'm not sure it is a typo. I think nick wants to invoke it right away but also reference it later.

Comment: @rasmeister: Could be. Fairly obvious to just call it after defining it though.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You made a typo. It is _immediately invoked function expression_

Comment: @SagarV: Both terms are used, and mean the same thing.

Comment: @SagarV: There's no official term. Call it whatever you want.

Comment: I've renamed the question as it's related to how I've used IFFE so it's not just another undefined javascript function post on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you will want to do to change this, if you want the `enableBulkAction` to be available for reference AND you want to invoke it right away is to make this change:

```
var enableBulkAction = function () {
        if ($("#frmProductManagement input:checkbox:checked").length > 0) {
            // any one is checked
            $('#ddlBulkAction').prop("enabled", "enabled");
        } else {
            // none is checked
            $('#ddlBulkAction').prop("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    };
enableBulkAction();
```

The rest of the script can remain as is.

Comment: Best not to post answers on questions like this. For one thing, if your answer is upvoted, it will prevent the OP deleting the question.

Comment: I wouldn't normally but as I mentioned I'm not convinced the OP made a typo but rather, wants to invoke the function right away and then later reference it.

Comment: @rasmeister I deliberately wrote it that way because when document model is loading in jquery I want to disable a dropdown but call that function when checkboxes are checked. I've used IFFE more when I was working with angular which is why it was included in the post I made.